# Individually italicize just a few long descriptions of acronyms

Tags: acronyms, acro

[image]

I am using the `acro` package to create acronyms and the list of acronyms. But I can't italicize the long description of individual way acronyms. The `\emph`, `\textit` and `\itshape` option are not working. these options are only working individually for the foreign option and not for the long option. As exemplified in the figure, I need to italicize only the description of the highlighted acronym. I am using the following code for defining the acronym:

```
\DeclareAcronym{4G}{
short = 4G,
long   = sistema de telefonia móvel de quarta geração,
class = Ac,
}

\DeclareAcronym{mMTC}{
short = mMTC,
long = comunicação massiva entre máquinas,
foreign = \emph{massive machine type communication},
class = Ac,
}


\DeclareAcronym{3GPP}{
short = 3GPP,
long = 3\textsuperscript{rd} Generation Partnership Project,
long-format = \itshape,
list-long-format = {\emph},
class = Ac,
}

\DeclareAcronym{CP}{
short = CP,
long = prefíxo cíclico,
foreign = \emph{cyclic prefix},
class = Ac,
}
```

Please I need some help with this for finishing my dissertation.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please prepare a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not completely clear to me if you want the long form of the acronym to *always* be in italics (in both document and list of acronyms) or only in the list of acronyms. In the first case use `long=\textit{...}` in the othercase use the `list` property:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareAcronym{A}{
  short = A ,
  long = upright
}
\DeclareAcronym{B}{
  short = B ,
  long = \textit{italic}
}
\DeclareAcronym{C}{
  short = C ,
  long = upright ,
  list = \textit{italic}
}

\begin{document}

\ac{A} \par \ac{B} \par \ac{C}

\printacronyms

\end{document}
```

[image]